# Access USB drive on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, usb-drive

I'm currently using a Ubuntu 14.04 server with command line access only. My `.html` files are on my Windows and I want to transfer them. What is the path in my Ubuntu server to get into my external device (in this case a USB drive, with the path letter of `G:\` under Windows)?

Comment: Removable disk or builtin?

Comment: It's a removable USB drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to connect your drive to the server.

Second: type `dmesg` just after connecting, at the end you should see what the system "calls" the drive.

Third: type `mount` to see if some automount mechanism already mounted the drive.

If not, mount the drive manually with `mount /dev/hdx /mountpoint`

Answer (score 9):

After attaching your USB drive to a server, run in terminal `lsblk`, you will see all storage devices, that are attached to your machine.
You may find there your USB drive (usually, they are named `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`, but is it NECESSARY to re-check that).

After that, you have to mount it to have possibility to read/write, for example:

`mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/`

where `/dev/sdb1` is your drive name that you noticed via `lsblk`, and `/mnt` - is a path, where do you wish to see filesystem of your USB drive.